# how to address a database column multiple times using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a project to access a database via REST, in which an old database has to be addressed in a modern way using `javax.persistence` annotations and JPA.

One of my classes fields look like this:

```
@Column(name = "properties_id", nullable = false)
private int propertiesId;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "properties_id", referencedColumnName = "dbid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private PropertyList propertyList;

@Id
@Column(name = "propertiesIdx", nullable = false)
private int propertiesIdx;
```

As you can see in the fields, the column `properties_id` is used as part of the primary key and as a foreign key. Unfortunately, there is no possibility to change the database layout.

In the application, I need both fields: one for joining the parent-table and another for addressing the property directly. 
But in the way it is currently implemented, it doesn't work.

Does somebody have an idea how to address this problem?

For further details of the problem please feel free to visit the git-repo:
https://github.com/SerNet/verinice-rest-service/tree/import

Comment: Change the "propertyList" field to be insertable/updatable, and make the "propertiesId" field not insertable/updatable. And show your `@IdClass`

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will have a look :)